# EXTJS - How to keep the DOM lighter while navigating through tabs in tabpanel?

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I have an extjs >4 application that uses tabpanels for menu. Under each tab there is content(Views that include containers etc).

I have noticed that extjs handles the DOM properly and does not render everything my app has. It only renders the active tab.

For example

```
       Ext.query('*').length = 805 //tab1
       Ext.query('*').length = 1052 //tab2
       Ext.query('*').length = 900 //tab3
```

I can see this, because I keep the state. So after I refresh the page the last activated tab is activated.
However, after I navigate through tabs the DOM gets a lot heavier. Ext.query('*') becomes

```
      Ext.query('*').length = 5500//example
```

So here is my question.

How can I keep the DOM lighter while navigating through tabs?

Best solution would be to keep the start state. For example, when activating tab1 keep only staff related to tab1, when activating tab2 keep only staff related to tab2 and so on like when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need [deferredRender:true](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-cfg-deferredRender). It defaults to true, just verify you don't change it.

Then, you can see [this example](http://extjs.eu/examples/#tabpanel-stateful) to find out how to keep the state (activeTab) of tab panel.

It should help because restoring state runs before the tab panel and its tabs are rendered so together with deferredRender it should wind up with only the active tab rendered.

Comment: I already keep the state of tabpanel. The problem is that dom gets heavier while navigating through tabs as it renders content. It would be nice to load only the contents of the activated tab and forget everything that has already been activated before on the other tabs

Comment: I wouldn't fiddle with that if you are not suffering from performance problems. If you really need to, you could destroy items of the inactive tab on inactivation and re-create them on activation, however, this may introduce more performance problems than switching tabs alone. Bottleneck is always DOM manipulation, inserting, removing, moving and resizing of elements.